# Creating a binary Tree and search function

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I am creating a ***binary tree*** and want to just **Search** function but I want to know how many nodes are visited to find a value. in the search function.

Here is the hearder file

```
#ifndef INTBINARYTREE_H
#define INTBINARYTREE_H


class IntBinaryTree
{

  private:
    struct TreeNode
    {
      int value;       // The value in node .
      TreeNode *left;  //pointer to left node
      TreeNode *right;  // Pointer to right child node
    };
    TreeNode *root;
  //private member functions

  void insert(TreeNode *&,TreeNode *&);

  void displayInOrder(TreeNode *) const;
  void displayPreOrder(TreeNode *) const;
  void displayPostOrder(TreeNode *) const;



  public:
    IntBinaryTree()
    {
      root = nullptr;
    }


    // Binary search tree
  int searchNode(int);
  void insertNode(int);
  void displayInOrder() const
    {
      displayInOrder(root);
    }


#endif // INTBINARYTREE_H
```

And here is the .cpp File I want to know how to for the search function if a value is not found zero and if  value is found how many nodes are visited ?

```
#include "IntBinaryTree.h"

void IntBinaryTree::insert(TreeNode *&nodePtr, TreeNode *&newNode)
{

    if (nodePtr == nullptr)
        nodePtr=newNode;    // insert the node
    else if (newNode->value < nodePtr->value)  `//search the left branch`
        insert(nodePtr->left, newNode);
    else
        insert(nodePtr->right, newNode); //search the right branch

}

void IntBinaryTree::insertNode(int num)
{
    TreeNode *newNode= nullptr; // pointer to a new node

    //create a new node and store num in it

    newNode = new TreeNode;

    newNode->value= num;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = nullptr;

    //insert the node

    insert(root, newNode);

}
int IntBinaryTree::searchNode(int num)
{
  TreeNode *nodePtr = root;

  while(nodePtr)
  {

    if (nodePtr->value==num)
    {
      cout<<"Node found"<<num<<endl;
    }
    else if (num < nodePtr->value)
      nodePtr = nodePtr->left;  // look to the left side of the branch if less than the value of the node
    else
      nodePtr = nodePtr->right; // look to the right side of the if not less than the value .
  }
```

return 0;
    }

Here is the Mainfile

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IntBinaryTree.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    IntBinaryTree tree;

    cout << "inserting nodes" << endl;
    tree.insertNode(5);
    tree.insertNode(8);
    tree.insertNode(3);
    tree.insertNode(12);
    tree.insertNode(9);
    cout << "Done.\n";
    tree.searchNode(5);
     return 0;}
```

Can you please code it for me and edit and explain it briefly how does it work ?

Comment: What is `TreeNode *&nodePtr` supposed to mean? Do you want a pointer or a reference.

Comment: nodePtr is a pointer to a TreeNode structure, and also a reference to a pointer to a TreeNode structure.  This means that any action performed on nodePtr is actually performed on the argument that was passed into nodePtr.

Comment: i can see that you are new on stackoverflow. please don't change your question like that. ask one thing, and if you have a new problem, create a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your includes are wrong.

There is a `#include "IntBinaryTree.cpp"` in your main.cpp. Because of this the insert member (and many others) exist twice. General rule: Never include cpp files.

Just remove the line, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you now I don't know how to deal with serch funciton for how many nodes has it met before finding a value to me .